# Adding content to a TreeViewItem programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, controls, treeviewitem

I'm trying to create a new TreeViewItem with a control in it like:

```
<TreeViewItem>
   <TreeViewItem.Header>
       <StackPanel>
           <Button/>
       </StackPanel>
   <TreeViewItem.Header>
<TreeViewItem>
```

Except, I'd like to do it at runtime (I'm using C#), but I can't work out how to do this. Can you help?

This is my code that I'm using to generate the node. Somewhere in here I would like to insert a numeric up/down control. I don't have that control yet, but for arguement's sake, let's say that I want to insert a button.

```
    private void TreeView_AfterSelect(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeView.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            if (((vcvscompiler.DataTypes.dataObjectv)(TreeView.SelectedNode.Tag))._vcardName.re == "adr_work")
            {
                foreach (string k in ((vcvscompiler.DataTypes.dataObjectv)(TreeView.SelectedNode.Tag))._prefs)
                {
                    TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();
                    newChild.Header = k;
                    treeView1.Items.Add(newChild);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

WPF:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTaskTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button content="This is a button!" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Can you put the `DataTemplate` in a resource?

Comment: Sorry; I thought you were using `.HeaderTemplate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new TreeViewItem {
    Header = new StackPanel {
        Children = {
            new Button { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, how do I add an event to the new control. They don't seem to be recognised in the context.

Comment: If you want to add an event handler, you'll need to break out a variable, since you can't add handlers in instance initializers.