# IEnumerable and creating StackPanels in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, ienumerable, stackpanel

Okay so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203316/adding-content-to-a-treeviewitem-programmatically) is awesome and easy to understand. I would like to implement a `StackPanel` into a `TreeViewItem` in that exact way. However, when I try to set the `Orientation` of the panel, the comiler complains about implementing `IEnumerable`.

Here's my `TreeViewItem` -> `StackPanel` implementation:

```
public static TreeViewItem newnode = new TreeViewItem()
{
       Header = new StackPanel {
           Orientation.Horizontal
       }
};
```

I haven't worked with `IEnumerable` before, but I tried implementing it by importing `System.Collections` and then setting my class to inherit from `IEnumerable`. After doing that I get a compiler error that says my class does not implement `System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`.

After looking at a few [online resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) I learned that apparently `IEnumerable<T>` contains `GetEnumerable()`.

First of all, am I on the right track? If so, how do I get this setup correctly?

Also, if I need to inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` what would I put in the `<>` if I am not working with some kind of `List` or `Template`?

Thank for your help.

**Exact Compiler Error as Requested**

`'Project.Folder.Class' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'`

Comment: Can you show the exact error you were getting from the compiler about implementing `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Yeah, I think you may have read the initial error wrong... it probably didn't mean for you to implement `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to initialise a specific property on an object, you should use the `Object Initialiser` syntax by naming the property you wish to initialise:

```
TreeViewItem newNode = new TreeViewItem()
{
    Header = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal}
};
```

In your case, the compiler is telling you that you can't initialise a `StackPanel` using the `Collection Initializer` syntax.

This:

```
new StackPanel 
{
    Orientation.Horizontal
}
```

Will produce the error you're seeing:

```
Error   1   Cannot initialize type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
```

Because you're trying to initialise the StackPanel as though it was a collection of `System.Windows.Control.Orientation` objects, e.g. `List<Orientation>`.

[Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx).