# How to use code-behind to create StackPanel -> Border -> Background

Tags: c#, wpf, background, stackpanel

I'm trying to set properties of a `TreeViewItem` -> `StackPanel` in c# like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203316/adding-content-to-a-treeviewitem-programmatically?lq=1). It seems to make a lot of sense until I get to the part where I try to edit the `Background` in my `Border`. `Borders` have `Background` objects in them, but for the life of me I can't set a color or anything. It seems to be inconsistent because I can add `Content` to a `Label` by simply saying, `Content = "Title"`.

Anyway, this is my code:

```
public static TreeViewItem childNode = new TreeViewItem() //Child Node 
{
     Header = new StackPanel
     {
         Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
         Children =
         {
             new Border {
                 Width = 12,
                 Height = 14,
                 Background = ? //How do I set the background?
             },
             new Label {
                 Content = "Child1"
             }
         }
     }
};
```

PS - I have the same problem when trying to add a `BorderBrush`

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason you chose this approach over a view/view model type approach?

Comment: I'm still starting out with MVVM, and find it easier to not use sometimes.

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) may go into more detail than you would like, but it may simplify your WPF development considerably.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Background` property accepts an `Brush`. Therefore, the code can set the color as follows:

```
MyLabel.Background = Brushes.Aquamarine;
```

Or this:

```
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
MyLabel.Background = myBrush;
```

To set any color, you can use `BrushConverter`:

```
BrushConverter MyBrush = new BrushConverter();

MyLabel.Background = (Brush)MyBrush.ConvertFrom("#ABABAB");
```

Setting the property to the `LinearGradientBrush` in code:

```
LinearGradientBrush myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();

myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 0.5));
myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 1.0));

MyLabel.Background = myBrush;
```

For you it would look like this:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem childNode = new TreeViewItem()
    {
        Header = new StackPanel
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,

             Children =
             {
                 new Border
                 {
                     Width = 12,
                     Height = 14,
                     Background = Brushes.Yellow, // Set background here
                 },

                 new Label 
                 {
                     Content = "Child1", 
                     Background = Brushes.Pink, // Set background here
                 }
             }
        }
    };

    MyTreeView.Items.Add(childNode);
}
```

Comment: This is all very helpful. I notice whenever you set the `Background` you have `object.Backgroun = myBrush;`. As you can see, my border doesn't really have a name. Is there anyway to add to it inside the `Border`, like I have in my question?

Comment: @Ericafterdark You need to save it to a variable. Applying an `x:Name` in XAML is really no different than saving a control to a private class variable.